# how to color a number (e.g. red) if the number is negative

Tags: grails, gsp

I have the following GSP:

```
<g:formatNumber number="${mietvertragInstance.mietsaldo}" type="number" minFractionDigits="2" format="#,##0.00"/>
```

if number is negative I want to display it red, otherwise leave it standard.

Comment: <g:formatNumber number="${mietvertragInstance.mietsaldo}" type="number" minFractionDigits="2" format="#,##0.00"/>

Answer (score 2):

Here a simple example

```
<g:if test="${mietvertragInstance.mietsaldo < 0}">
    <span style="color:red;"><g:formatNumber number="${mietvertragInstance.mietsaldo}" type="number" minFractionDigits="2" format="#,##0.00"/></span>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <g:formatNumber number="${mietvertragInstance.mietsaldo}" type="number" minFractionDigits="2" format="#,##0.00"/>
</g:else>
```

Comment: Also you may set color through CSS

Comment: @user3647093 if the answer is the perfect solution, then why not accept it?